# Why doesn't my "rate my app" message send me to the website when I say yes?

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I tried having a message pop up after my app opens 5 times and sending the user to a website if they click on "yes" but it doesn't work for some reason, could anyone help me out? im a beginner so i'm assuming its a pretty simple mistake, here is my code in app delegate.m

' @interface AppDelegate ()

```
@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger launchCount = [prefs integerForKey:@"launchCount"];
    launchCount++;
    [prefs setInteger:launchCount forKey:@"launchCount"];



    return YES;
```

and this is the code in view controller.m:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger launchCount = [prefs integerForKey:@"launchCount"];
    if (launchCount ==5) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"like this app?" message:@"rate us on the app store!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"no thanks" otherButtonTitles:@"yes", @"remind me later", nil];
        [alert show];
    }

}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        //user hit remind later , so ignore
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 2){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://facebook.com"]];
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSInteger launchCount = [prefs integerForKey:@"launchCount"];
        launchCount = 0;
        [prefs setInteger:launchCount forKey:@"launchCount"];
    }


}'
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but an unrelated comment: is it your intention to take them through this path _every_ 5 launches if they press Yes? If not, stop resetting the counter when they press yes (and if so, stop reading the counter value before you reset it to 0, since you don't care what it was before).

Comment: Now possibly related to your problem... when you create the alert, do you need to set yourself as delegate? If not, how should your `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method be reached?

Comment: To solve the problem you need to use the debugger and set breakpoints at important steps.  For example is the "launch count" being stored properly?

Comment: @mah thanks for your answer , the counter works fine it only displays the fifth time I open the app.

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks for your answer, what do you exactly mean by stored properly?

Comment: @StephenDeverell it only _appears_ to work fine, since currently your callback is never being reached! Once you fix the problem (hinted at in my second command, and directly addressed in rmaddy's answer), you'll find that it gets called every 5 launches following a "Yes" response. A simple review of your code will point this out.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

1. You never set the delegate for the alert view so none of your alert view delegate method will ever be called. To fix this, set the `delegate` parameter:

   ```
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"like this app?" message:@"rate us on the app store!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"no thanks" otherButtonTitles:@"yes", @"remind me later", nil];
   ```
2. You are checking the wrong button indexes and you shouldn't hardcode button indexes. Use the following:

   ```
   -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
       if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex) {
           // user hit yes
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://facebook.com"]];
           NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
           NSInteger launchCount = [prefs integerForKey:@"launchCount"];
           launchCount = 0;
           [prefs setInteger:launchCount forKey:@"launchCount"];
       } else if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex + 1){
           // user hit remind later , so ignore
       }
   }
   ```
3. As mentioned in the comments below your question, you probably don't want to reset `launchCount` when the user taps "yes". Doing so means the user will be asked to rate the app again 5 launches after they choose "yes". That would be annoying. There's also no reason to read the launch count just before resetting it. So just do:

   ```
   -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
       if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex) {
           // user hit yes
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://facebook.com"]];
       } else if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex + 1){
           // user hit remind later , so ignore
       }
   }
   ```

Also note that `UIAlertView` has been deprecated. Unless you are also supported iOS 7 or earlier you should be using `UIAlertController` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I just changed nil to self and 1 to 2 and 2 to 1 and everything is working, thanks again !